# How to make M2E (Maven for eclipse) include required eclipse projects in WAR

Tags: eclipse, maven, war, m2eclipse

I'm starting to use Maven (M2E) on Eclipse.
I have two projects

->Tools

->Main

The Main project requires the Tools project. I add "Tools" under the "Main"->"Deployment assembly" option, and when exporting to WAR, the WAR will automatically contain also Tools.jar. This is correct.
Now I installed M2E on the Main Project, to manage some spring dependencies. When I edit the pom.xml, Maven starts, and correctly downloads the Spring jars, but it removes the Tools project from the "Deployment assembly" option (it disappear from the org.eclipse.wst.common.component eclipse configuration file)
As a result, when I export the WAR from Eclipse->Export, the war will not contain Tools.jar, so the webapp will not work.

How do I configure pom.xml to do what Eclipse does with the "deployment assembly"?
That is, package all classes and resources and jar dependencies of the Tools project?

I think that I'm missing some understanding of Maven, but I've not been able to google about it?

thank you

Comment: If you have a Maven project (pom.xml) the truth is only the pom file and not Eclipse anymore...

Comment: I understand what you mean: I have to do everything from Maven. So the question is: how do I create a dependency to a project of mine in the workspace? I'm trying, but I do not find a quick guide about that...

Comment: Using Maven as well... and if you import that project into Eclipse by default Eclipse resolves dependencies via the workspaces...